# How to stop Update-FormatData complaining about a loaded file

Tags: powershell, format

Is there a workaround to stop Update-FormatData complaining about a loaded file when the format file is already loaded in the session

I will answer my question here: as I can't post an answer to my question for 8 hours.
I did enough Google but could't find anything before posting the question then I thought there must be a Get- for the format data!!!

I think this should do it

```
$T = Get-FormatData | Where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "ffps.data"}
if ( $T -eq $null ){
    Write-Debug "Load $formatfile"
    Update-FormatData -PrependPath $formatfile    
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the command you used and the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean this error:

Update-FormatData : There were errors in loading the format data file:
Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\test.Format.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already present from "Microsoft.PowerShell".

To suppress the error use the ErrorAction parameter:

```
Update-FormatData -AppendPath C:\test.Format.ps1xml -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

UPDATE

There is a cmdlet to get the format data (v2), Get-FormatData:

```
Get-FormatData -TypeName ffps.data
```